# E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels:1:

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

On giving the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I am getting the following error:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels:1:
Extra junk at end of file.
```

Also a red circle with negative sign is present on the upper right corner of the desktop and I am unable to access update manager.

Answer (score 0):

- **Try**

`sudo /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

---

- **Before** `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels`

> ```
> ../../../linux-headers-3.2.0-65/scripts/kconfig/streamline_config.pl\00\00\00\0‌​0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\.............‌​
> ```

- **After** `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels`

> ```
> // File autogenerated by /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal, do not edit
>     APT
>     {
>       NeverAutoRemove
>       {
>         "^linux-image-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-image-extra-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-signed-image-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-backports-modules-.*-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-headers-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-tools-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>       };
>     };
> ```